# SQL UPPERCASE UPDATE STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle

update name_surname_dictionary set name=upper("helen") where seq='1';

I have a problem . I wanna make this upper like this;

result:"HELEN"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
update name_surname_dictionary set name=upper('"helen"') where seq='1';
```

And don't forget to make a commit to Your statement.